# Программа, которая для каждого 1<=n<=100 находит наименьшее треугольное число, кратное n, сумма цифр которого также кратна n. Как её ускорить?

Tags: python, оптимизация, арифметика, числовые-последовательности

```
# Программа, 
# которая для каждого 1<=n<=100 
# находит наименьшее треугольное число, 
# кратное n, сумма цифр которого также n. 

def triangle_number(n):
    return n * (n + 1) // 2

def digit_sum(n):
    return sum(map(int, str(n)))

for n in range(1, 101):
    k = 1
    while True:
        tn = triangle_number(k)
        if tn % n == 0 and digit_sum(tn) % n == 0 and digit_sum(tn) != 0:
            print(f"n = {n}, k = {k}, tn = {tn}")
            break
        k += 1
```

Данная программа работает чересчур медленно, поэтому успевает вывести только первые 39 нужных чисел из ста. Получается последовательность: 1, 6, 3, 1128, 55, 6, 1596, 15576, 36, 190, 163878, 1128, 378885 тощо.

Пожалуйста, помогите оптимизировать код таким образом, чтобы выводились все 100 требуемых чисел.

Comment: В ```triangle_number``` и ```digit_sum``` на разных итерация выполняют одинаковые операции. это можно оптимизировать создав свой или взяв готовый декоратор кэширования [пример 1](https://habr.com/ru/post/709280/), [пример 2](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/dekoratory-python/keshirovanie-znachenij-dekoratorah/) . В условии проверку ```digit_sum``` стоит вынести на первое место.

Comment: Ещё кажется в стоит избегать преобразования числа в строку и обратно и написать digit_sum не так «красиво», а через обычное целочисленное деление и остатки

Comment: Ещё можно сэкономить умножение и деление, т.к. следующее треугольное число вычисляется из предыдущего простым прибавлением k+1

Comment: Да и `digit_sum` в условии считается два раза (в худшем случае), имело бы смысл присвоить результат в какую-то переменную и потом уже проверять. P.S. Хм, хотя так у меня медленнее считает. Очень интересно...

Answer (score 2):

1. оптимизация digit_sum :

```
digit_sum_divider = int(10**5)  # подобрать оптимальное 10**5 ... 10**3, в зависимоти  от размера кеша конкретного процессора
digit_sum_precalc = [ sum(map(int, str(n))) for n in range(digit_sum_divider) ]
def digit_sum(n):
    ret =0 
    while True:
        ret += digit_sum_precalc[ n%digit_sum_divider ] 
        n = n//(digit_sum_divider)
        if n==0:
            return ret
```

2. Оптимизация основного цикла:
   Если перебирать `k+=1`, то будет много "пустых" циклов: в среднем, для каждого n-го будет выполнено условие `triangle_number(k)%n==0`. Полезно заранее рассчитеть размер шага по k.

Путь для k условие выполнено `triangle_number(k)%n==0`, найдем минимальное s для которого `triangle_number(k+s)%n==0`
Посчитаем:

```
triangle_number(k+s) % n ==0
(k+s)*(k+s+1)//2 %n ==0
(k+s)*(k+s+1) % (n*2) ==0
( k*(k+1) + s*(2*k+1 + s)  )  % (n*2) ==0
( k*(k+1) % (n*2) + s*(2*k+1 + s) % (n*2) ) % (n*2) ==0 # транзитивность взятия остатка
(  s*(2*k+1 + s) % (n*2) ) % (n*2) ==0 # k*(k+1) % (n*2) ==0 - поскольку для k выполнено условие triangle_number(k)%n==0
(  (s%(n*2)) *( (2*k+1) % (n*2) + s  % (n*2) ) ) % (n*2) ==0
```

Видим, что k входит в уравнение для шага по k, только в составе выражения `(2*k+1) % (n*2)`, но это выражение пробегает ограниченное число значений, а значит, можно меморизовать величину шага как функцию `(2*k+1) % (n*2)`.
Получим:

```
def add_for_k( a , nn ):
    for s in range(1, nn+1 ):
        if  s*(s+a) % nn ==0 :
            return s

def main():       
    for n in range(1, 45):
        adds_k = [ add_for_k(i, 2*n) for i in range( n*2) ]
        k =  adds_k[1] 
        while True:
            if digit_sum( (k*(k+1))//2) % n == 0:
                break
            k += adds_k[ (2*k+1) % (n*2) ]
        print(f"n = {n}, k = {k}, tn = {triangle_number(k)}")
```

Что приведет к росту производительности, примерно в 10 раз, что, впрочем, все равно недостаточно, поскольку размер искомого k экспоненциально растет с ростом n.

Comment: Большое спасибо!